# How to write blogs that include latex math in Github Pages using R Markdown?

Tags: latex, jekyll, r-markdown, github-pages, mathjax

I am planning to start a blog using Githug Pages. I want to write the blogs using R markdown and there will be a lot of latex math in them.

I have tried so many times but failed. I have used mathjax, pandoc and this and that. Nothing has worked. I have been able to get myusername.github.io up and running but the latex math portions are not rendered. Part of the reason for my failure may have something to do with my limited understanding of how a website is generated in general.

**Can someone please provide a step-by-step guide to write a blog, that has latex math, in Github Pages using R Markdown?**

Comment: You might want to add a link to your GitHub-pages page.

Comment: You can read http://tinyheero.github.io/2015/12/06/rmd-to-jekyll-protect-eqn.html

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger https://arjunpoddar.github.io//2016/01/01/Finding-k/    The reason I did not add it was because I was rebuilding the pages time and time again. I followed many solutions, but nothing worked.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I have read and tried tinyheero's instructions. For a person who is not well-versed in building websites and webpages, it did not help much. What I am a looking for is a beginner's guide.

Answer (score 2):

R Markdown is not supported by default by Jekyll 3. There's an [open issue on the R Markdown repository](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/304).

Other static site generator like [Nikola offer math support by default](https://getnikola.com/handbook.html#math).

[Kramdown Jekyll's default Markdownn engine supports Math blocks](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#math-blocks) though.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely give Nikola a try. There are few places/blogs where people have shed some light on how to render latex in Jekyll but those are not enough for someone as illiterate as me in building websites.

Comment: Perhaps you could give [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com) a try: you can use any Jekyll version / configuration with it. Also, any Static Site Gen, with [GitLab Pages](https://pages.gitlab.io). Just an idea though :)